How to access files in different folder but same repo in Go?
Suppose we have the following folder structure:
|-- Repo
|   |-- Data
|   |   |-- Sets
|   |   |   |-- Set1.json
|   |-- Tests
|   |---|-- Case1
|   |---|---|-- main.go


If I want to access the Set1.json file, how would I do that from main.go? Suppose I'm allowed to provide the relative path with respective to repo, i.e. Repo/Data/Sets would be provided. Is there a way for me to immediately figure out the absolute path involving that relative path on any system?
My solution was using os.Getwd to get the current location and then use:
tmp := filepath.Dir(filepath.Dir(currDir))

To get to the sibling of the parent of the folder where main.go was. Then I just do:
res := filepath.Join(tmp, "Data/Sets") 
Or
res := filepath.Join(tmp, "Data\\Sets")

And this would get me the absolute path to the Sets folder. Is there a smarter way to get there somehow? It should work on any system.

Another way to do it:
tmp2 := filepath.Join(tmp, "Data/Sets")
res := filepath.Clean(tmp2)```

You can't reliably reference files in other source packages, but you can embed files and reference them.
Just define a go file in your data/sets directory (Go Playground):
package sets

import (
    _ "embed"
)

//go:embed set1.json
var Set1 []byte

the reference that from other packages:
package main

import (
    "<your.module.here>/data/sets"
)

func main() {
    _ = sets.Set1
}


You can use os.Executable() instead of os.Getwd(), which supports get the right path when executing binary files anywhere.
